# How can I add multiple content in a pseudo-selector?

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.maincontainer
{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.sec
{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: max-content;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
 ul{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     list-style: none;
     width: 100%;
 }

.line   
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.circle
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #1AEF81;
}

.odd::after
{
    content: "25/08/2021 8:00 PM";
    position: absolute;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform: translate(-43%, 250%);

}
.odd::before
{
    content: "Approved By Co-ordinator";
    position: absolute;
    width: max-content;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: max-content;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform: translate(-45%, 70%);
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.even::before
{
    z-index: 1;
    content: "25/08/2021 8:00 PM";
    position: absolute;
    top: -90px;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform: translatex(-44%);
}

.even::after
{
    content: "Approved By Co-ordiantor";
    content: "25/08/2021 8:00 PM";
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    width: max-content;
    height: max-content;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    transform: translatex(-45%);
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.events 
{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

.eventCards
{
    width: max-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: small;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.13);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.507);
    margin: 15px;
}

.name
{
    display: flex;
    place-items: center;
}

.name p{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: #505050;
}


.right
{
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.eventCards .status
{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#one
{
    background-color: #1AEF81;
}

#two
{
    background-color: #ffc400;
}

#three
{
    background-color: #c40d0d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="maincontainer">
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <ul>
                <li class="circle odd"></li>
                <li class="circle even"></li>
                <li class="circle odd"></li>
                <li class="circle even"></li>
                <li class="circle odd"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="events">
            <div class="eventCards">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="name">
                        <h3>PHP-DC Introduction Session</h3>
                        <p>8sd7f8sd6f</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>27-08-2021</p>
                </div>
                <p class="status">Status : </p>
                <div class="right" id="one">
                    Approved
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="eventCards">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="name">
                        <h3>PHP-DC Introduction Session</h3>
                        <p>8sd7f8sd6f</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>27-08-2021</p>
                </div>
                <p class="status">Status : </p>
                <div class="right" id="two">
                    Pending
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="eventCards">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="name">
                        <h3>PHP-DC Introduction Session</h3>
                        <p>8sd7f8sd6f</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>27-08-2021</p>
                </div>

                <p class="status">Status : </p>

                <div class="right" id="three">
                    Rejected
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have to add multiple texts in **pseudo-selectors** using it's **content** property. Is there any way to do it?

I would like to achieve something like this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rr75.png)

I have used the :before and :after pseudo-selector of the middle circle and place the text there, but I think there must be an optical way to do it right?

Comment: Give more details like example code which you tried so far

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Try adding white-space: pre; and use \a for new line in content. 
Example:
`
.odd::before {
    content: "Approved By Co-ordinator \a test";
    white-space: pre;
}`

Comment: Oh yes it is working but can i target that **test** separately and change it's colour ?

Comment: No you cannot. You cannot style part of a pseudo element

Comment: @Deepkk-9 Sadly no.. A better option is if you use span/div and not pseudo-elements. You can achieve the same with real elements and it will be more flexible

Comment: @CloudySkies ha yes but, if i add a div here then the div part will also be rendered on the circle and i don't want that, is there any other method that will help me to achieve the result shown in img ?